# Как бороться с этим кодом рекламы?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Мой хостинг-провайдер всё время в конце страницы ставит код:

```
<!-- ><!-- "><!-- '><!-- ;><!-- -->
</textarea></form></title></comment></a></div></span></ilayer></layer></iframe></noframes></style></noscript>
</table></script></applet></font>

<!-- inner counter-->
<script type="text/javascript">
pseudocounter = 'http://register.h19.ru/g/pseudocounter.js';
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + pseudocounter + '?' + Math.random() +  '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>

<!-- STAT.SU -->
<script src="http://auth.tbn.ru:8080/jdb/pp/statsu.no-cache.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>statSuBanner("64713", "301" , "");</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://stat.su/?u=64713" target="_blank"><img
src="http://service-stat.tbn.ru/1.gif?u=64713&bn=301" width="1" height="1"
border="0"/></a>
</noscript>
<!-- STAT.SU -->
```

и вот результат:

```
<html>
<!--Мой код//-->
</html><!--этот поганый код//-->
```

Этот код рекламы  моло что сам не работает (а лишь выводит уродскую надпись наподобие "аunction(G){var F=G||"и т.д.) да ещё и запарывает работу моих js на странице, пробовал бороться:

1) в конце страницы ставил одинарный тег `<frameset>`, но это не работает в Firefox

2)  пробовал писать:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var anitireclama=document.getElementsByTagname("script");
antireclama[antireclama.length-1].innerHTML="";
antireclama[antireclama.length-2].innerHTML="";
antireclama[antireclama.length-3].innerHTML="";
// -->
</script>
```

- но ведь их теги создаются после выполнения моего кода и этот вариант не работает!
Помогите плиз я уже всё перепробовал!

ps:Есть полный доступ к php может какойто код php запускать вместе со страницей!?
ps: Это чисто в теоритических целях я некаких правил нарушать несобираюсь!

Comment: может, потратиться на хостинг, а не использовать бесплатный?

Comment: а мне это уже нестолько ради работы страницы сколько в "научных целях" необходимо!

Comment: Практически наверняка, пытаясь отключить рекламные показы, вы нарушаете правила пользования хостинга, поскольку рекламные показы - это и есть оплата услуг хостинга. Поэтому лучше так не делать.

Comment: ну ладно я небуду делать но чисто теоритически помогите как это сделать!? или вы сами незнаете как!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жди загрузки документа полностью! window.onload=function(){reklama.style.display='none';};
Может еще попробывать добавить css в котором у ненужных тебе элементов(генерируемых скриптом), прописать display:none; Лучше даже у их общего родителя, попробуй как нить так ...

P.S. я не прочел полностью все то, что ты написал, так, что может советую уже проделанное тобой ранее ...

Comment: а уних вся фишка в тегах script&rt; и без идов а как с ними бороться

Comment: Человек правильно написал. Либо жди загрузки страницы и удаляй затем все ненужные элементы с помощью явыскрипта. Либо просто напиши что-то вроде:
</body></html>
<p style="display: none;">
в опере работает...

Comment: <p style="display: none;"> работает везде кроме firefox

Answer (score 2):

Я сам долго смеялся конечно, но это работает )) Это на jquery, честно говоря, не смог переделать это на нативную яву, но что это возможно, однозначно... jquery сам на яве написан...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = '<html>' + $("html").html();
    html = html.substr(0, html.indexOf("startPosition"))  + '</body></html>';

    $('*').html('');
    document.write(html);
});
```

Идея такая... Напишите `<p style="display: none;">` все равно... А в этом скрипте сделайте предварительную проверку на браузер. Если firefox, то пусть будет такая замена.. И да... Нужно записать этот скрипт в отдельный файл, иначе startPosition в СКРИПТЕ воспринимается как конечная точка... )) Ну или там другими какими-то вариациями попробовать.... Вообщем, все тупо =))

И еще... Если Вы говорите, что имеется полный доступ к функциям php, то попробовать покапаться в настройках через ini_set и ей подобные функции. Ведь где-то это добавление должно быть прописано!..

Я поддерживаю народ, который чуть выше написал, что это плохо все... Я сам бы никогда не стал такого делать. Но мне как и Вам стало просто интересно возможно ли это..

Comment: Попробую спасибо!